# Postgresql order by column and by timestamp

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, calculated-columns

I have table that is orgainsed with comments and replies. I am using the following query to get parentids and from there get the replies (replyid) that should relate to them.

The problem I face is that when I get the data, I can organize it by a column (replyid) but I cannot organize those by a time stamp.  Or it seems that postgresql ignores the second order by altogether.

```
     parentid     |     replyid      | commentowner  | username |                                              commentbody                                              |        postcreation        
------------------+------------------+---------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 gLKysUwsL5CVHRIR | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | bob@none.com  | Bobert   | Some Lame Comment....                                                                                 | 2018-05-08 13:21:43.049563
 yt1SLuFzRz1Nlri2 | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | bob@none.com  | Bobert   | another parent comment                                                                                | 2018-05-08 13:22:05.677257
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | bob@none.com  | Bobert   | latest reply                                                                                          | 2018-05-08 13:22:37.535039
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | bob@none.com  | Bobert   | no I am the latest                                                                                    | 2018-05-08 13:22:52.868424
                  | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | bob@none.com  | Bobert   | I am a response to  to another parent                                                                 | 2018-05-08 13:23:42.167327
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | mike@none.com | Mikey    | I am a response to  to another parent                                                                 | 2018-05-09 08:27:22.733211
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | mike@none.com | Mikey    | Mike sent this!!                                                                                      | 2018-05-09 08:27:50.1
```

and the users table:

```
username  |                            socialkey                             | emailaddress  |                                  bannerpic                                   |                                     avatarpic                                      
----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bobert   | 9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a | bob@none.com  | https://craftedin.co/static/images/user/headers/59d9bce7c33561.24964635.jpg  | https://craftedin.co/static/images/user/avatars/thumbs/59159be40a8c76.26091804.jpg
 Mikey    | 3bcd6c5f811ba06aa49c2df9504fe5416f35702b78bcdc15ecbd5137fabdca59 | mike@none.com | https://i.pinimg.com/originals/29/85/16/298516524d3ed9eb35ea9aae0f111ab3.jpg | https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg
```

If it will help make a sort of codepen or something for this let me know and I will try to make that happen.

Here is the query that I am running:

```
with parents as (select distinct replyid from comments where commentowner = (select emailaddress from users where SocialKey = ('9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a')) and parentid IS NOT NULL LIMIT 5 ), socialkeys as (select distinct socialkey,emailaddress,avatarpic from users) select distinct comments.parentid, comments.replyid,comments.username, comments.commentbody,comments.postcreation   from comments left join parents on parents.replyid = comments.replyid left join socialkeys on comments.commentowner = socialkeys.emailaddress where parents.replyid = comments.replyid order by  replyid, postcreation;
```

Here is the data I am receiving:

```
     parentid     |     replyid      | username |                                     commentbody                                     |        postcreation        
------------------+------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 gLKysUwsL5CVHRIR | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | Some Lame Comment....                                                               | 2018-05-08 13:21:43.049563
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | latest reply                                                                        | 2018-05-08 13:22:37.535039
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | no I am the latest                                                                  | 2018-05-08 13:22:52.868424
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Mikey    | I am a response to  to another parent                                               | 2018-05-09 08:27:22.733211
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Mikey    | Mike sent this!!                                                                    | 2018-05-09 08:27:50.140229
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | bob                                                                                 | 2018-06-28 14:22:07.131133
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | Oh so this really does work?                                                        | 2018-06-28 14:27:02.956613
                  | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | this is a reply                                                                     | 2018-06-28 17:41:49.071165
 wpdcBFUft0r597IK | 4WMFSMSTSomjdoD9 | Bobert   | this is parent comment number 5 I think the database is set to limit 5...           | 2018-06-28 18:15:47.534429
 yt1SLuFzRz1Nlri2 | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | Bobert   | another parent comment                                                              | 2018-05-08 13:22:05.677257
                  | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | Bobert   | I am a response to  to another parent                                               | 2018-05-08 13:23:42.167327
                  | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | Bobert   | Another lame     coment reply                                                       | 2018-05-19 12:55:56.090902
 pw22kSb7MdA9Nx5G | MD3jA9znknV9c3p7 | Bobert   | This is a new comment from bobbert on the new interfce                              | 2018-06-28 18:03:30.05851
 bffV59nEQRg5YtP3 | tIZYNjkyzoHhKfza | Bobert   | This is comment # 6... This should show up becasue it is the newest! of the newsts! | 2018-06-28 18:16:12.823547
```

Here is what I want to receive. All the comments have been gathered and ordered by replyid, but I want those to also align with the time of their entry. I hope this makes sense. I have tried to graph everything out.

```
         parentid     |     replyid      | username |                                     commentbody                                     |        postcreation        
    ------------------+------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
     gLKysUwsL5CVHRIR | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | Some Lame Comment....                                                               | 2018-05-08 13:21:43.049563
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | latest reply                                                                        | 2018-05-08 13:22:37.535039
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | no I am the latest                                                                  | 2018-05-08 13:22:52.868424
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Mikey    | I am a response to  to another parent                                               | 2018-05-09 08:27:22.733211
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Mikey    | Mike sent this!!                                                                    | 2018-05-09 08:27:50.140229
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | bob                                                                                 | 2018-06-28 14:22:07.131133
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | Oh so this really does work?                                                        | 2018-06-28 14:27:02.956613
                      | 3X77KW5t9X43Psfp | Bobert   | this is a reply                                                                     | 2018-06-28 17:41:49.071165
     yt1SLuFzRz1Nlri2 | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | Bobert   | another parent comment                                                              | 2018-05-08 13:22:05.677257
                      | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | Bobert   | I am a response to  to another parent                                               | 2018-05-08 13:23:42.167327
                      | BG7mm4cj7Q3Ujffs | Bobert   | Another lame     coment reply                                                       | 2018-05-19 12:55:56.090902
     pw22kSb7MdA9Nx5G | MD3jA9znknV9c3p7 | Bobert   | This is a new comment from bobbert on the new interfce                              | 2018-06-28 18:03:30.05851
     wpdcBFUft0r597IK | 4WMFSMSTSomjdoD9 | Bobert   | this is parent comment number 5 I think the database is set to limit 5...           | 2018-06-28 18:15:47.534429
     bffV59nEQRg5YtP3 | tIZYNjkyzoHhKfza | Bobert   | This is comment # 6... This should show up becasue it is the newest! of the newsts! | 2018-06-28 18:16:12.823547
```

Am I doing this completely wrong? Or am I missing something simple?

Let me know please, thanks.

Comment: *"Here is what I want to receive... All the comments have been gatherd and ordered by replyid..."* No they haven't. If they had been ordered by replyid, the ones starting with '3' and the one starting with '4' would be together. (Like they are in the first set of data.) Clarify what you really want, and paste `create table` and `insert` statements into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 2 outputs it looks like the entry with parentid = wpdcBFUft0r597IK is in wrong order according to you. There is only one entry with that parentid, so your query doesn't care which order your parentid come out in. If you do want to be ordered by parentid's postcreation then try to change your query to the following.

```
with parents
as (select replyid,
           min(postcreation) postcreation
    from comments
    where commentowner = (select emailaddress
                          from users
                          where socialkey = ('9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a'))
          and parentid is not null 
    group by replyid limit 5),
socialkeys
as (select distinct socialkey,
                    emailaddress,
                    avatarpic
    from users)
select distinct parents.postcreation,
                comments.parentid,
                comments.replyid,
                comments.username,
                comments.commentbody,
                comments.postcreation
from comments
left join parents on parents.replyid = comments.replyid
left join socialkeys on comments.commentowner = socialkeys.emailaddress
where parents.replyid = comments.replyid
order by parents.postcreation,
    comments.replyid,
    comments.postcreation;
```

I changed your parents CTE to a group by so you can use the MIN POSTCREATION in your order by. I also qualified the ORDER BY fields with the table names incase there is ambiguity in which REPLYID to sort on.

-HTH

Comment: there is some syntax error with the group by . I am just barely looking at to try tofigure out what the problem is.

Comment: @ApertureSecurity apologies, I updated my answer. (Moved the Limit 5 to after the group by and added parents.postcreation to the Select Distinct so Order by will work.)